# Combining .rar extraction

Tags: extract, rar

I've recently downloaded 7 .rar files which needs to get extracted and to output only one file. How do I to make them extract only one output and to do not extract 7 files, please?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: @Parto, I'm trying to `unrar 1.rar 2.rar 3.rar 4.rar 5.rar 6.rar 7.rar` to `folder`

Comment: @AmurayuYukiko unrar ?.rar will pick up [0-9,a-z,A-Z].rar and recreate the file or files of there are more

Comment: Could you please clarify your problem? Multipart rar archives usually end in .rar, .r01, .r02, ... Extracting the first file will use the data from the others.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

If you are using the GUI, I believe you can just right click and "Extract Here" or whatever the equivalent of it is.

If you want to use a command, open a terminal and `cd` to the directory then use:

```
unrar x -e file.part1.rar
```

Where `file.part1.rar` is the first part of the whole thing. The other files need to be in the same folder.

If you can't execute the `unrar` command, you'll need to install it using:

```
sudo apt-get install rar unrar
```

Source: http://www.zyxware.com/articles/636/how-to-unrar-and-combine-multiple-rar-files-in-ubuntu

Comment: Using that will extract 7 files, no ? I've trying using GUI, selecting the 7 files, right-click, Extract File, this extracts me 7 files also !

Comment: Don't select the 7 files. Select only the first file, right-click, Extract file. This should extract all of them. Does it only extract the first file? Make sure that they are all named the same, except for the "part#" part.

Comment: After that I've extracted them following your advice, I've got one folder into which there is 7 files `file_name.7z.001 file_name.7z.002 file_name.7z.003 file_name.7z.004 file_name.7z.005 file_name.7z.006 file_name.7z.007`. How do I to use them ? Do I need another extraction ?

Comment: Yes, another extraction. Right click on the first and extract.

Comment: @AmurayuYukiko This really looks downloaded warez (they are the only ones packaging like that). You shouldn't bother with it as it is virus ridden anyway.

Comment: @AlaaAli if I have 10 file parts in .rar format, do I need to only run `unrar x -e file.part1.rar`? does it automatically look for other parts?